# clear authoritative explanation of numpy axis numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting confused by contradictory explanations of what exactly the term axis means in numpy and how these constructs are numbered.

Here's one explanation:
Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension.
A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes:
the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and
the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).

So, in this 3x4 matrix ...

```
>>> b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

(axis 0) is the 3 rows
(axis 1) is the 4 columns

So the rule might be ...

In an MxN matrix, (axis 0) is M and (axis 1) is N.

Is this correct?

So, in a 3 dimensional matrix AxBxC 
(axis 0) is A
(axis 1) is B
(axis 2) is C

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you said is correct, with the exception of

> Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension.

Axes are also defined for one dimensional arrays - there is just one of them (i.e. axis 0).

---

One intuitive way to think about axes is to consider what happens when you apply a reduction operation over one axis, such as summation. For example, suppose I have some array `x`:

```
x = np.arange(60).reshape(3, 4, 5)
```

If I compute `x.sum(0)` I am "collapsing" `x` over the first dimension (i.e. axis 0), so I end up with a `(4, 5)` array. Likewise, `x.sum(1)` gives me a `(3, 5)` array and `x.sum(2)` gives me a `(3, 4)` array.

An integer index into a single axis of `x` will also give me an output with one fewer axis. For example, `x[0, :, :]` gives me the first "row" of `x`, which has shape `(4, 5)`, `x[:, 0, :]` gives me the first "column" with shape `(3, 5)`, and `x[:, :, 0]` gives me the first slice in the third dimension of `x` with shape `(3, 4)`.

Answer (score 4):

If someone need a clear idea, here is the picture:

[image: Numpy Axis 0 and Axis 1]

Answer (score 1):

A smart way to remember this is that 
axis =0 collapses the rows 
Whilst 
axis=1 collapses the columns

a three 3*4 array when operated upon with sum function and axis =0 would yield 1*4 output that is all the rows would be collapsed and the aggregation would be done column-wise.

The same function when performed with axis=1 would collapse the columns and yield 3*1 output with aggregation along rows.

the image link would further help assimilating this concept.
[Example for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86vPO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to imagine this in 3D, I personally feel it is difficult to imagine when we go to 4D or 5D... So I decide to give up but rather think about this in an implementation perspective. Basically, it has N-number of nested `for` loop, and if we want to reduce one specific axis, we just work on the for loop of that axis. For example, if given a 3x3x3 tensor, `axis = 0` is the for loop of a[**i**][x][x], `axis = 1` is to loop a[x][**i**][x], `axis = 2` is to loop a[x][x][**i**]. 4D, 5D, ... should have the same way.

```
def my_reduce_max(a, axis=0):
    b = [[-1 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            tmp_max = -1
            for i in range(3):
                if axis == 0:
                    get_value = a[i][j][k]
                elif axis == 1:
                    get_value = a[j][i][k]
                else:
                    get_value = a[j][k][i]
                tmp_max = max(get_value, tmp_max)
            b[j][k] = tmp_max

    return b

a = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
print(a)
my_reduce_max(a, 2)
```

Comment: Of course, this is just a very naive code to think through the idea. An optimized implementation should reduce the number of these for loops.